# Objective C - calling a method of another object with delay

Tags: objective-c

How can I call a method of another object after a delay?

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:@"myObject"
           afterDelay:time];
```

The above code works but "myMethod" needs to live in the same object. How can I do it to a method in another object? (i.e [self.otherObject myMethod]?

p.s: I know I can always do the call from "myMethod" but thought that there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[otherObject performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:@"myObject"
           afterDelay:time];
```

Comment: "maybe? :)" If someone knows how to make an A-Bomb and you don't, and you ask it, would you appreciate getting the same idiotic tone? Its stackoverflow here not trollface united

Comment: Damn, I was too busy looking at the "selector" parameter part that I totally overlooked the self at the beginning of the code. Thanks Joris.

Answer (score 0):

performSelector is a method of NSObject. Which means that any subclass of NSObject, which initially is any class in your code can use that method.